# Spring MVC with Hibernate - One to Many

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, orm

I have the following simple scenario:

```
Cars table: Id, Name, Model

Cars Schedule table:Id, CarId, ScheduleTime, ScheduleDate
```

I am using Spring MVC with Hibernate, with the structure of:

- Domain
- repo
- repoImpl
- service
- serviceImpl

what I need to do is displaying the car name in the list of the Cars Schedule without having to add a field called CarName in the CarsSchedule table.

What is the best practice for doing this?

Comment: can you add the entity classes to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Car` entity you should have

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "car")
private List<CarsSchedule> schedules;
```

I assumed that the relation is `@OneToMany`, but you can just switch it to `@OneToOne private CarsSchedule schedule;`, if that's the case.

And in `CarsSchedule` entity, this

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CarId")
private Car car;
```

With this setup, once you have the `carsSchedule` instance in your controller (and model), you can display the name of the car on the page with `#{carsSchedule.car.name}`.

Comment: I am getting: Property 'car' not found on type com.dev.app.domain.CarSchedule

Comment: Did you get getter and setter methods for these fields?

Comment: One more thing, while I am inserting a new car or carschedule should I take care of anything else? Should I add some annotations?

Comment: You should configure `cascade` option on `m-to-n` annotations, per your needs. If you, for example, put `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` on `schedules` field, when you persist a car, all the schedules will be persisted also.

Comment: Aha, I meant for the Car Field/Property in the schedule domain class, Should I add the @Transient so that it knows it shouldn't be inserted

Comment: No, `@Transient` means that field will never be read or written from/to database. You might use it, but with a little different setup, you would have to set it always by yourself. If cascade option is empty, no operation will be cascaded to that relation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a one-to-many relationship in the table Cars Schedule:

```
//in class CarsSchedule
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "CAR_ID", nullable = false)
public Stock getCar() {
    return this.car;
}
```

Then in the controller, you retrieve the list of CarSchedule (that has also the Car into it) and put the list into the model:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "car-list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String getList(HttpSession session, Map<String, Object> model) {
      //get the list from the service
      List<CarsSchedule> list = service.getCarScheduleList();  
      //put into the model
      model.put("form", new PersonUserRoleForm());
      return "mymodel";
}
```

then you have a mymodel.jsp maybe, where you can retieve the variable mymodel

You can follow this simple tutorial:
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Ciao

Comment: I am not using xml to relate tables and even if so, how can I get the car name in the model, can you please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting the annotations on the property accessor method, you can simply add

```
@Transient
public String getName() {
    return car.getName();
}
```

It will be invisible for your database but visible for all other layers. In JSP you would access it as `${carsSchedule.name}`, and it would be an immediate child in your JSON or XML if that is the representation you use

Even if your annotating properties themselves you can still do

```
@Transient
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return car.getName();
}
```

I recon that your main idea is to avoid persisting another field. Note just that the transient annotation is the javax.persistence.Transient and it has no implication to the serialization just tells the persistence provider to ignore the field upon persisting